# How to use a haskell sandbox in cabal 3.x?

Tags: haskell, cabal

cabal 3.x doesn't work for me.

I wanted to use a sandbox, as in cabal 2.x.
But the installation of packages seems randomly to succeed or not.

The documentations says, the v1- commands are still available.

But how is such a thing possible:

`cabal v1-build` says `cabal: Encountered missing or private
dependencies`

and

`cabal v1-install --only-dependencies` says 
`All the requested packages are already installed`

Log of the shell:

```
lists0@duin ~/programming/haskell/mysoftware (git)-[Streamly] % cabal v1-build
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: mysoftware-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: unordered-containers (dependency of mysoftware)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: unordered-containers, mysoftware)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: mysoftware, unordered-containers
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring mysoftware-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
data-default -any,
fclabels -any,
hashable -any,
megaparsec -any,
parser-combinators -any,
sorted-list -any,
typerep-map -any,
unordered-containers -any

1 lists0@duin ~/programming/haskell/mysoftware (git)-[Streamly] % cabal v1-install --only-dependencies                                       :(
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.

lists0@duin ~/programming/haskell/mysoftware (git)-[Streamly] % cabal v1-build                      
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: solver failed to find a solution:
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: mysoftware-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: unordered-containers (dependency of mysoftware)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: unordered-containers, mysoftware)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: mysoftware, unordered-containers
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring mysoftware-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing or private dependencies:
data-default -any,
fclabels -any,
hashable -any,
megaparsec -any,
parser-combinators -any,
sorted-list -any,
typerep-map -any,
unordered-containers -any
```

Comment: (1) If you create a new project with `cabal init` and add `unordered-containers` to its dependencies, do you still have the same problem? (2) On a tangential note, consider asking a separate question about your issue with cabal 3, as it is supposed to cover all use cases of the v1 commands, including `v1-sandbox`.

Comment: "unknown package: unordered-containers" looks fishy to me. Perhaps you need to `cabal update`, then try `cabal v1-install --only-dependencies` again?

Comment: Why do you want to use a sandbox? What does it offer you that the normal `cabal v2-*` usage does not?

Comment: I see no mention of `cabalv1-sandbox init` in the question. It's required for sandboxes to work. But one should use the newer sandboxless nix-like commands whenever possible. The sandboxes model is obsolete.